# How is this equation valid?

Tags: operational-amplifier, circuit-analysis, power-electronics

[image][image]

I am trying to understand the Howland circuit.But how is the following equation formed .Isnt it should be(vi-vo)/R

Comment: If you want a solution, you need to make an attempt at one

Comment: That's (former MIT professor Bradford) **Howland** not Holand. I believe he's still with us, although quite elderly.

Comment: (vi - vo)/R isn't an equation.

Answer (score 3):

By virtue of voltage division, and the fact that no current enters the op amp at the input terminals, the voltage at the negative input is \$\frac{v_{out}}{2}\$

Because this is an op amp circuit with negative feedback, the positive input terminal must be at the same voltage as the negative input terminal.

The current between the input and that node is indeed \$\frac{v_{in}-v_{out}}{R}\$, and the sum of that and the current between the op amp output and that node must be \$\frac{v_{out}}{2R}\$